# Using the Fitness app without my Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, fitness+

I have an Apple Watch and an iPhone and they're paired together. Right now, my iPhone tracks my calories burned only while I have my Apple Watch on. But, I only wear the Apple Watch when I'm working out.

I'm wondering if it's possible to still track calories during all the hours I have my iPhone, but do not have my Watch.

Comment: This is surely a setting you can change. "You can use the Fitness app  to track your daily activity, set a move goal, see your progress, and see your movement trends over time—**even if you don’t have an Apple Watch**." (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph9a08e004e/ios). I do not use an Apple Watch but I use the Fitness app on iPhone and it works perfectly well. Perhaps you need to allow Fitness app to access your location?

Comment: Also, this can be done without the Fitness app. You can simply use the Health app too.